# python не видит модуль django

Tags: python, linux, django, pip

Мучаюсь с linux mint

Установлены (не помню уж почему) несколько версий python. 3.6, 3.7, 3.8.

Устанавливаю джангу через pip3, он устанавливается на версию 3.8.
Устанавливаю django-grappelli через pip3, но устанавливается на версию 3.6.
Удаление\установка не помогают
Возможно, из за того, что какое-то время назад пытался разобраться с виртуальными средами, но в итоге бросил...

Джанга устанавливается в /home/efor/.pyenv/versions/3.8.5/lib/python3.8/site-packages
При том, что grappelli установился в /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages.

Любая ссылка на джангу в проге выдает ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django' (запускал на idle 3.8)

sys.path.append('/home/efor/.pyenv/versions/3.8.5/lib/python3.8/site-packages') решает проблему, но странно вписывать это до импортов. Плюс только на 1 запуск, после чего нужно опять выполнять эту строку

Приходится класть папку с модулем в папку с программой или в /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (он есть в sys.path)

Притом, просто так перенести модули в /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages не дает.  permission denied.
пришлось через sudo cp -r /home/efor/site/django /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/
это нормально, вообще?

Подскажите, как навсегда добавить /home/efor/.pyenv/versions/3.8.5/lib/python3.8/site-packages в список путей, который выдает sys.path либо указать pip3 куда складывать скачанное?
Нужно, чтобы не из терминала работало, а из idle

Можно ли удалить ненужные питоны, или в системе что-то работать перестанет?

Comment: Удалите всё и поставьте нужную версию

Comment: удалил 3.6 теперь система не грузится) Failed to start Light Display Manager

Comment: А новую версию поставили?

Comment: оставил установленную 3.8

Comment: Так вы удалили всё, потом установили 3.8 версию и не грузит систему теперь?

Comment: не удалял 3.8, но удалил 3.6

Answer (score 2):

Если у Вас установлено несколько версий Python будьте осторожны. Вы можете легко запутаться в установках дополнительных пакетов.

Для того, что бы установить пакет допустим numpy используйте :

```
pip3.6 install numpy
pip3.7 install numpy
pip3.8 install numpy
```

Для того, что бы запустить файл .py

```
python3.6 your_file.py
python3.7 your_file.py
python3.8 your_file.py
```

Comment: у тебя разве `py` на `linux` стоит?

Comment: правда ошибся, исправил )